# Create an instance with new, with nested objects as arguments

Tags: javascript, object

I want to create an instance of the object Player, which as an instance of the object Weapon nested in it.

For example, **player1 should start the game with a dagger**.

I tried different things but the nested object (weapon) is not in the player instance.

```js
function Weapon(name, damage) {
  this.name = name;
  this.damage = damage;
}

function Player(name, life) {
  this.name = name;
  this.life = life;

  this.weapon = {
    name: name,
    damage: damage
  };
}

const player1 = new Player("Joueur 1", 100, dagger);

const dagger = new Weapon("Dague", 5);
const sword = new Weapon("Epée", 10);
const axe = new Weapon("Hache", 15);
const flail = new Weapon("Fléau", 20);
```

What is the right syntax to add this weapon as a nested object?

Also, the weapon may change during the game.

Comment: "Right now I am getting" — No, you're getting an error message.

Comment: @Quentin I don't see it in the console.
And why downvoting my post, what was wrong seriously? Two character spaces for indentation...

Comment: Click the Run code snippet button. The error is unmissable. (Possibly you are running some code locally which is *different* to the code you shared with us … which isn't helpful).

Comment: Note that your constructor for `Player` takes two arguments: `name` and `life`. Now look at how you're calling it: with three values.

Comment: @Quentin Because the rest of the code is not relevant and if I share hundreds of lines of code, it will be boring for everyone.
I want to make this problem a solution for others, and so keep it simple, if someone finds the solution.

Comment: @HereticMonkey the nested object this.weapon is not an argument?

Comment: @GrégoryHuyghe — Providing a [mcve] is great! We like it when you do that. The trick is that code you share has to demonstrate the problem you are asking about and not a different one.

Comment: @Quentin My problem is that I don't manage to put the weapon dagger into a player instance, no matter the error. I can't be clearer about this.

Comment: If you don't see it between the parentheses after `Player`, it's not something the body of the function knows about (well, technically it does but let's not open a can of worms).

Comment: @GrégoryHuyghe — Provide an [mcve] that demonstrates your attempt. You said that it was setting the weapon name to Weapon, the code you have won't do that, or anything like that.

Comment: @Quentin I removed it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you're looking for something like this, you're currently trying to pass a parameter but the constructor isn't expecting it. I've given 2 examples of how you could achieve this.

```js
function Weapon(name, damage) {
  this.name = name;
  this.damage = damage;
}

function Player(name, life, weapon) {
  this.name = name;
  this.life = life;

  this.weapon = weapon;
}

const dagger = new Weapon("Dague", 5);
const player1 = new Player("Joueur 1", 100, dagger);

const player2 = new Player("Joueur 1", 100, new Weapon("Dague", 5));

console.log(player1);
console.log(player2);
```

Comment: @Thanks, glad you were here.